# Is it possible to find a Vue component based on its "el"?

Tags: vue.js

Suppose I have this component:

```
<b-select id="selectfield" :src="['a', 'b']"></b-select>
```

Which renders into:

```
<select id="selectfield">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
</select>
```

Can I "find" the instance for my `b-select` component based on its "el" (which in this case would be its id)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible with the "public" API but you can get the Vue instance from the `__vue__` DOM property of any element that is a root mount for a component.

```
document.getElementById('selectfield').__vue__
```

As to whether or not you should use it.. Vue's author says the Vue devtools rely on it, so it's unlikely to change. See https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5621